# Maven Connection Timed out error - Eclipse Luna

Tags: maven, eclipse-luna

I have eclipse Luna downloaded. I created a simple maven project (Skipped Archetype selection). When i clicked finish got the below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss6kz.jpg)

Then i did a "Run As-> Maven Install" on the pom file and got below error:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

I tried above same steps after deleting the settings.xml from .m2 directory. I tried downloading mvn get command and got the same error..

I am doing from laptop. I am not using any proxy settings, I can access the below url which gets displayed during maven build:

```
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
```

The error which i get is (mvn -e get logs):

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connect to repo.maven
.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.24.215] failed: Connection timed
out: connect
```

Comment: Behind a firewall/proxy ?

Comment: No.. I am doing it in my laptop at home.. No proxy.. No firewall.. I am able to hit the repo.maven.apache.org [maven central] through my browser successfully....

Comment: Browser is something different that command line...check your configuration in your browser if you are using firewall/proxy etc. The connection time out looks like this...

Comment: @khmarbaise You were right. Fire wall was the issue, antivirus was blocking the request under firewall. It is working now